# EF6 preventing not to create Index on Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm using `EF6` code first approach to create database. When i add migration and update database it always create `Non-cluster Index` for every foreign key in the table by default.

[image]

**My Question:** Is there any global setting for EF6 to not create `Non-Cluster index`on foreign key ?

I have search and found the following solutions

[Solution 1: Remove index line from migration before updating database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22226233/4154016)

Solution 1 not suits me because i have a lot of tables and my `db` is already created. Manually remove index creation line takes much much time.

Moreover i'm also using `fluent api` is there any option related to this issue ?

Comment: first of all, take a look at this article : [When did SQL Server stop putting indexes on Foreign Key columns?](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/When-did-SQL-Server-stop-putting-indexes-on-Foreign-Key-columns.aspx)

you can write a SQL query and execute it in your migration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a simple solution to this, but I have an idea about what you could do: create a custom migration generator.

Migration generators are the components that are responsible for creating the SQL script that is run on the database from the migration code files. I assume you have SQL Server based on the screenshot. In this case, you can write a custom sql generator that simply overrides the index creation operation so that if the index is non-clustered, nothing is written to the script:

```
public class NoIndexGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
  protected override void Generate(CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation)
  {
    if (!createIndexOperation.IsClustered)
    {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you have to register this component in the `Configuration` class of the migration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyCtx>
{
  public Configuration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

    // Add this line to register the sql generator
    this.SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new NoIndexGenerator());
  }
}
```

Now if you run `Add-Migration`, you'll have a normal migration file, with the CreateIndexOperation in it. But if you run `Update-Database`, the non-clustered indices will not be created. You can also check this if you run `Update-Database -Script`. The resulting script does not have the non-clustered indices.

If you want, you can go even higher up in the pipeline, and create a custom C# migration scaffolder. It applies the same logic as the sql generator:

```
internal class NoIndexMigrationCodeGenerator : CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
{
  protected override void Generate(CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
  {
    if (!createIndexOperation.IsClustered)
    {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can register it in the `Configuration` class like this:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyCtx>
{
  public Configuration()
  {
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

    // Add this line to register the C# code generator
    this.CodeGenerator = new NoIndexMigrationCodeGenerator();
  }
}
```

Now, if you run `Add-Migration`, the CreateIndex operations will disappear from the generated migration cs files as well.

I'd probably go with the second solution (it can be confusing for others reading your code to see that there are CreateIndex operations in the migration cs file, but not in the SQL scripts), but ultimately it is your choice :)

You can play with other properties of the `createIndexOperation` parameter of the `Generate()` methods to implement more sophisticated index filtering, if you have to.

If you want, you can also override the Generate methods that have a parameter of type `DropCreateIndexOperation` but since indices are dropped with a 'drop-if-exists' pattern, I don't think this is necessary.

**EDIT**

While the above code samples seem to work, to be fair and follow general best-practices and principles, you should probably include calls to the base methods in both generators after the if statements.

Comment: Shouldn't those overriden methods be calling the base `Generate` method when it is clustered?  Or if the idea is to just not create the index either way then what's the point of the `if` statement?

Comment: @juharr That's a valid point. I will confirm that this code indeed does not work as expected and then edit to fix.

Comment: This was a big help for me in creating a custom migration code generator to avoid indexes on FK that are part of the PK.

Comment: @juharr To be honest, I'm not sure what's happening exactly, but the code works. Probably the indices for primary keys and the indices created via the `Index()` method are generated on another code path. But I'll include an edit just in case, because I do think it's a valid point.

Comment: @AkosNagy I noticed there are `Generate` and `GenerateInline` methods depending on how it's creating the code.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I think this might have been an 'If all you have is a hammer...' kinda situation.

The answer that I gave before works (and I stand by it, because it is totally fun and awesome), but it's probably not the best way to do it.

Recently I checked all the default conventions EF uses the generate the database, and there is one that's responsible for generating the non-clustered indices on FK-s. Just remove that convention altogether, and the problem is solved:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   // using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>();
 }
```

Comment: I suppose you could add it as a comment in https://dotnetfalcon.com/stackoverflow-adventures-dont-create-non-clustered-index-for-foreign-keys-with-entity-framework-code-first/ :D

Answer (score 1):

After trying to use `CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator` I start to think in way to override the `ForeignKeyIndexConvention`.
So I implemented the check that allows to skip adding index on Primary Key column by assuming that PK naming convention was not overrided.

```
public class ForeignKeyIndexConventionFix : ForeignKeyIndexConvention
{
    private const string Id = "Id";

    public override void Apply(AssociationType item, DbModel model)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        }
        if (item.Constraint == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (item.IsForeignKey)
        {
            if (IsPrimaryKeyColumn(item.Constraint))
            {
                return;
            }                
        }
        base.Apply(item, model);
    }

    private static bool IsPrimaryKeyColumn(ReferentialConstraint constraint)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> dependentColumns = constraint.ToProperties.Select(p => p.Name);

        if (dependentColumns.Count() == 1)
        {
            string dependentColum = dependentColumns.First();

            if (dependentColum.Equals(Id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then override your `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>();
  modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<ForeignKeyIndexConventionFix>();
}
```

There was problem to debug solution - `Console.Write` and `Debug.Write` were not giving output - so I just put tracing to some text file in temp location. Maybe there is a better way..?

And the code source of original implementation helped to figure out how to get dependent column names: https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/ModelConfiguration/Conventions/Edm/Db/ForeignKeyIndexConvention.cs

Answer (score 0):

With EF Core 6.0, you need to remove ForeignKeyIndexConvention form all the convention sets that includes it. Here is a working solution:

Create a new ConventionSetBuilder class:

```
public class CustomSqlServerConventionSetBuilder : SqlServerConventionSetBuilder, IConventionSetBuilder
{
    public CustomSqlServerConventionSetBuilder(ProviderConventionSetBuilderDependencies dependencies, RelationalConventionSetBuilderDependencies relationalDependencies,
        ISqlGenerationHelper sqlGenerationHelper) : base(dependencies, relationalDependencies, sqlGenerationHelper)
    {
    }

    public override ConventionSet CreateConventionSet()
    {
        var cs = base.CreateConventionSet();

        //ForeignKeyAddedConventions
        var foreignKeyAddedConvention = cs.ForeignKeyAddedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (foreignKeyAddedConvention != null)
            cs.ForeignKeyAddedConventions.Remove(foreignKeyAddedConvention);

        //ForeignKeyRemovedConventions
        var foreignKeyRemovedConventions = cs.ForeignKeyRemovedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (foreignKeyRemovedConventions != null)
            cs.ForeignKeyRemovedConventions.Remove(foreignKeyRemovedConventions);

        //EntityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions
        var entityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions = cs.EntityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (entityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions != null)
            cs.EntityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions.Remove(entityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions);

        //KeyAddedConventions
        var keyAddedConventions = cs.KeyAddedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (keyAddedConventions != null)
            cs.KeyAddedConventions.Remove(keyAddedConventions);

        //KeyRemovedConventions
        var keyRemovedConventions = cs.KeyRemovedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (keyRemovedConventions != null)
            cs.KeyRemovedConventions.Remove(keyRemovedConventions);

        //ForeignKeyPropertiesChangedConventions
        var foreignKeyPropertiesChangedConventions = cs.ForeignKeyPropertiesChangedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (foreignKeyPropertiesChangedConventions != null)
            cs.ForeignKeyPropertiesChangedConventions.Remove(foreignKeyPropertiesChangedConventions);

        //ForeignKeyUniquenessChangedConventions
        var foreignKeyUniquenessChangedConventions = cs.ForeignKeyUniquenessChangedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (foreignKeyUniquenessChangedConventions != null)
            cs.ForeignKeyUniquenessChangedConventions.Remove(foreignKeyUniquenessChangedConventions);

        //IndexAddedConventions
        var indexAddedConventions = cs.IndexAddedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (indexAddedConventions != null)
            cs.IndexAddedConventions.Remove(indexAddedConventions);

        //IndexRemovedConventions
        var indexRemovedConventions = cs.IndexRemovedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (indexRemovedConventions != null)
            cs.IndexRemovedConventions.Remove(indexRemovedConventions);

        //IndexUniquenessChangedConventions
        var indexUniquenessChangedConventions = cs.IndexUniquenessChangedConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (indexUniquenessChangedConventions != null)
            cs.IndexUniquenessChangedConventions.Remove(indexUniquenessChangedConventions);

        //ModelFinalizingConventions
        var modelFinalizingConventions = cs.ModelFinalizingConventions.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ForeignKeyIndexConvention);
        if (modelFinalizingConventions != null)
            cs.ModelFinalizingConventions.Remove(modelFinalizingConventions);
        return cs;
    }
}
```

And replace the ConventionSetBuilder within your DbContext configuration:

```
public partial class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        ...
        optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IConventionSetBuilder, CustomSqlServerConventionSetBuilder>();
    }
}
```